# How to properly import namespaced code used in Webpack/es6/babel?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

I'm currently working on a ReactJS project and I'm trying to come up with an effective way to namespace my code. The most obvious solution I have is to do the following:

```
let API = {
  init: function() {
    //  Do some type of initialization here
  }

  makeACall: function() {
    // Make a call
  }
};
```

Previously, I'd make a file of functions each of which were exported like:

```
export function makeACall() {
  // Make a call
}
```

And then I'd import it into another file using: `import { makeACall } from 'utils/api';`

However the problem here is that I may have another function in the imported file called `makeACall`. So what I'd like to do is namespace it. Question is: how do I import individual functions from an object/namespace or is this not possible?

Comment: Why would you have multiple functions with the same name in one file?

Comment: You can theoretically "import" names from an object using a destructuring assignment, but in general you should do namespacing in ES6 via modules only.

Comment: You know that you can alias the imported identifiers using `as`?

Comment: Yeah apparently I should have just read this post: http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html